# Ajax вешает страницу

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Я не слишком опытен в этой теме, но по какой-то причине при ajax запросе начинает утекать оперативная память вплоть до 700+ Мб, при этом страница зависает.
Есть маленький js код, собирающий несколько полей, и отправляющий их на сервер, где создается текстовый файл с этими полями.

JS:

```
var mail = [];

function send(mail) {
    mail[0] = $('#sfera').val();
    mail[1] = $('#reg').val();
    mail[2] = $('#mail').val();
    var data = mail;
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'mail.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {
            'mail' : data
        },
    });
    mail.length = 0;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['mail'])) {
    $mailArr = $_POST['mail'];
    $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . "/stat/statistics.txt", "a+");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($mailArr); $i++) {
        fwrite($fp, $mailArr[$i] . "\r\n");
    }
    fwrite("-----\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

UPD: Заработало, видимо, когда изменил

```
<form method="POST" id="intel" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Отправить">
```

и в JS немного изменил

```
var mail = [];

function call() {
    mail[0] = $('#sfera').val();
    mail[1] = $('#reg').val();
    mail[2] = $('#mail').val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'mail.php',
        data : {
            'mail' : mail
        },
    });

    mail.length = 0;
}
```

Comment: Удалите вот эту `mail.length = 0;` непонятную конструкцию. И это `var data = mail;` зачем у вас, если можно `'mail' : mail`? Зачем принимаете `mail`, если заполнение массива идет внутри функции?

Comment: да это мои попытки исправить как-то это зависание: mail.length = 0 - обнуление массива, что с ним, что без него, 'mail' : mail - пробовал, тоже ничего не вышло, принимаю mail по той же причине, да и друг один, более прошаренный, чем я, говорит что нужно в функции передавать, даже то, что объявлено глобально, иначе мало ли что.

Comment: во всех браузерах утекает? Для такой утечки достаточно один раз выполнить запрос? или оно как то циклически делается? Результат запроса возвращается?

Comment: и в опере и в хроме утекает, достаточно один раз выполнить, на серваке файл не создается, значит виснет где-то в ajax. Попробовал передавать в другой php файл, там запрос на принятие не писал, в теории не должно было ничего произойти, но страница снова повисла, значит что-то происходит еще до отправки, либо во время отправки на сервер.

Comment: Но по опыту программирования, мне кажется где-то тут спрятался бесконечный цикл, вот только, тут все предельно просто, и я не представляю, где он может быть.

Comment: @Nurk33RUS где/как вызывается `send`?

Comment: Igor, при нажатии кнопки

Comment: @Nurk33RUS - безусловно, я Вам верю. Однако, для предметного разговора надо добавить в вопрос относящийся к делу html и javascript.

Comment: была кнопка типа button, на onclick повесил вызов send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте форму так ajax`ом отправить

```
<form method="POST" id="formx" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()" >
   <input твои поля >
   <input type="submit" class="submit" value=">">
</form>
```

и обработать ее таким скриптом:

```
function call() {
    var msg   = $('#formx').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'путь к твоему mail.php',
      data: msg,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#какой то блок').after(data);
      },
      error:  function(xhr, str){
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
      }
    });
}
```

ну и в php напишите, что Вам нужно:

```
<?php if ($_POST) { ну и в нем запросите свои POST и сделайте, что нужно } ?>
```

Comment: сделал, как вы сказали, но с небольшими правками: var msg   = $('#formx').serialize(); - тут было пусто, заменил на свой массив из примера, data: msg, - передавало unredined поля в php, вернул свою передачу. Возможно ошибка была в параметрах формы.